# Phrase for repeatedly passing something from one person to another?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a phrase that describes:

> I got it from him, who got it from another person, who got it from another.

I have been discussing such a situation with a friend and am wondering whether there is a word or phrase for that situation, such as 'daisy chain'.

Comment: When you say "it got it from him", is *it* a piece of information? Like you *heard* it from him? If so, then use "I heard on the grapevine" or "I got it from the grapevine". Or "the rumor mill has it" or simply "rumor has it". See also "the game of telephone". If *it* is a physical object, and the passing along is deliberate, sequential, then "it's been passed down"; if the passing along is more accidental, less organized, then "it's been passed around".

Comment: Please amend your Q. to clarify what "it" is, as explained by DanBron

Comment: Also consider ***handmedowns***, which, e.g. were new when your parents bought them for your eldest sibling, and still in decent shape when he *handed them down* to your older sister, but we're looking a bit ragtag by the time she, in turn, *handed them down to you*. They're like heirlooms or legacies, but grodier.

Comment: Passing the buck

Comment: If its something odious, a hot potato.

Comment: If "it" is verbal, this is a Chinese Whisper.

Comment: It has been _relayed_ to you.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the buck

FROM:thefreedictionary.com

> http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+the+buck
>
> > pass the buck 
> >     Also found in: Dictionary, Thesaurus, Medical, Legal, Financial, Acronyms, Encyclopedia, Wikipedia.
> >     pass the buck
> >     Fig. to pass the blame (to someone else); to give the responsibility (to someone else). (See also The buck stops here.) Don't try to pass the buck! It's your fault, and everybody knows it. Some people try to pass the buck whenever they can.
> >     See also: buck, pass
> >
> > McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.
> >
> > pass the buck
> >
> > to make someone else responsible for something Bus companies say their drivers are causing delays, but they are just passing the buck again.
> >     See also: buck, pass

Passing the torch

> http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+the+torch

FROM:thefreedictionary.com

> > pass the torch
> >
> > Also found in: Dictionary, Thesaurus, Medical, Legal, Encyclopedia.
> >     Related to pass the torch: touch base, drop off, Keyed Up, no less, nothing short of, in the works, keen on
> >
> > pass the torch (to somebody)
> >
> > to give responsibility to someone The president of the company announced his retirement, saying it was time to pass the torch to someone younger.
> >
> > See also: pass, torch
> >
> > Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge University Press 2003. Reproduced with permission.
> >
> > pass the torch
> >
> > Also, hand on the torch. Relinquish responsibilities, a tradition, practice, or knowledge to another. For example, When the company's founder became too ill to continue, he passed the torch to his nephew . This metaphoric expression alludes to the ancient Greek torch race, in which a lighted torch was passed from one runner to the next. A translation from both Greek and Latin, the English version dates from the late 1800s.
> >
> > See also: pass, torch
> >
> > The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.
> >
> > pass the torch
> >
> > To relinquish (responsibilities, for example) to another or others.
> >     See also: pass, torch

Comment: Good suggestions, but please quote the relevant definitions here itself.